# Run s3cmd get in background

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am using `s3cmd` to get around ~11000 files from a publicly accessible s3 bucket (`s3://cgl-rnaseq-recompute-fixed`) to my EC2 container. I am using the following command:

`for i in $(cat tcga-manifest); do s3cmd get --requester-pays $i; done`

where `tcga-manifest` is a file with a list of files to get:

```
head -n3 tcga-manifest

s3://cgl-rnaseq-recompute-fixed/tcga/00065a62-5e18-4223-a884-12fca053a109.tar.gz
s3://cgl-rnaseq-recompute-fixed/tcga/0009f27d-a053-49b0-a030-ba9c1469224f.tar.gz
s3://cgl-rnaseq-recompute-fixed/tcga/000f476b-7d55-4fd1-8f72-622ab00e009b.tar.gz
s3://cgl-rnaseq-recompute-fixed/tcga/001313a7-fbd7-4a9a-a961-50c7433338e7.tar.gz
```

However, I want to run the get command in the background so that when I log out of the EC2 container, it still keeps running. Also, because I am downloading a large number of files, the ssh connection breaks. I tried using `&` which did not work:

`for i in $(cat tcga-manifest); do s3cmd get --requester-pays $i; done &`

How can I run the s3cmd get command in the background and logout of the EC2 container?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your script in a file and run it with

```
nohup bash <yourscript> &
```

that will allow your script to run after your session terminates.